# How do I export data from Azure Monitor to have infinite retention?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

We're running Azure Monitor for Containers, collecting logs and Prometheus metrics. Standard retention is available up to 730 days. I can'd find any export option to have the data available after that time. Is there any option to export the data collected in Azure Monitor?

Answer (score 0):

If you reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-platform-metrics#what-can-you-do-with-azure-monitor-metrics, it will point you to a few options for analyzing and storing your metrics data.

One option is to export to storage - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-archive-data.  You can find this in Monitor -> Diagnostic Settings

You could also stream monitor data to event hubs and then process it in whatever system you want to use - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/stream-monitoring-data-event-hubs.